# Install4j ShowErrorMessage doesn't work?

Tags: install4j

I just added the following to my install4j config:

```
+              <action name="" id="1260" customizedId="" beanClass="com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction" 
+                <serializedBean>
+                  <java class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
+                    <object class="com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction">
+                      <void property="script">
+                        <object class="com.install4j.api.beans.ScriptProperty">
+                          <void property="value">
+                            <string>boolean sixtyFourBits = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").equals("64");
+if (!sixtyFourBits) {
+    Util.showErrorMessage("Unfortunately, this application requires a 64-bit Mac");
+}
+
+return sixtyFourBits;</string>
+                          </void>
+                        </object>
+                      </void>
+                    </object>
+                  </java>
+                </serializedBean>
+                <condition>return Util.isMacOS();</condition>
+              </action>
```

When I run it on 64-bit Mac, it correctly does nothing.  When I run it on a 32-bit Mac, the installer quits silently, with no dialog box.  system.log shows:

5/26/13 3:34:00 PM /Volumes/lantern/Lantern Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub[83467] Unrecognized Java VM option ignored: 
5/26/13 3:34:19 PM [0x0-0xf6cf6c].com.install4j.3831-6452-7413-7646.1343[83467] Unfortunately, this application requires a 64-bit Mac

(I assume the first message is unrelated, given the timing, and given that the script actually runs)

Is there a method I should be using other than showErrorMessage?

Answer (score 0):

The failure occurs before the action can be run. Apparently you have added a VM option on the "Installer" node on the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step that prevents the 32-bit JVM from starting.

Comment: But if that is so, then how does that error message even make it into the logs?

Comment: The log file is not set up at that point yet. All this is done in the JVM and the JVM is not even running at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "Default execution mode" was set to "Unattended mode with progress dialog". At least, that's what it looks like.

If I change the "Default execution mode" (in the Installer settings) to "GUI mode", that should fix things (albeit at the cost of some pointless extra screens in the installer).